# Store ndarray as a blob in PostgreSQL with pandas

Tags: pandas, postgresql, numpy

I'm trying to store an ndarray from a pandas data frame
to postgres. Putting the ndarrays in an column and using `to_sql()` stores
them very inefficiently. Is there a more efficient way(memory wise) of doing this ?

Note: Of course normalizing the ndarrays into rows in a table would be much better for searching and maybe reduce memory usage, but this is specifically about keeping the ndarray since the structure dimensions are not precisely known beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `BytesIO` in combination with `numpy.save()` seems to do the trick. Also, explicit types in `to_sql` ensure `bytea` is used. Something like:

```py
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import String, LargeBinary


df = pd.DataFrame([file_path],columns=["filename"])
f = io.BytesIO()
np.save(f, blob_data)
f.seek(0)
blob = f.read()
df['image'] = [blob]
```

And then save it like:

```py
df.to_sql(con=engine, name=destination_table_name, schema=destination_schema_name, dtype={"filename": String, "image": LargeBinary})
```

To read it back do something like:

```py
df2 = pull_dataframe_from_postgres_function()
f = io.BytesIO()
f.write(df2["image"][0])
f.seek(0)
data = np.load(f)               #  data as a ndarray
```